# Is there a way to delay only a certain transition/animation for tooltips in Chart.js 3.x?

Tags: javascript, graph, chart.js, tooltip

I'm using Chart.js 3.6.0, and I'm trying to have a tooltip show up after a hover over a data point for 2 seconds, and when it triggers i want the fade-in etc to have a duration of 200 ms. If i understand the documentation correctly, I should be able to set these properties separate of each other, but when I try this they seem to mix the animations together or something like it: When I hover over a data point and move to another point I get a tooltip that is both faded in and changes position over 2 seconds, i.e. 2 seconds becomes the duration of all animations and not the delay.

I'm using these options for the tooltip right now:

```js
options: {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      animation: {
        delay: 2000,
        duration: 200,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**JSFiddle example:** https://jsfiddle.net/yzgxu5sm/

Is there a way to make this work with the built-in tooltip plugin, or do I have to make a custom plugin to make this work?

Comment: You can take a look at this discussion on github, it is a v2 answer but you can rewrite it to v3: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/discussions/8357